# How to make Gravity for multiple planets in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

What i'm looking to do is something similar to our solar system, where you are gravitically drawn to one planet till you leave it's pull, and then once you're on another planet be drawn to that gravity.

I have found many entries online about how to create gravity for a single planet, but none i've found work for multiple sources.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Projects I've already looked at were mainly for single planet gravity.

[unity 3.3, create local gravity on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044419/unity-3-3-create-local-gravity-on-object)

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13639/how-do-i-make-a-small-planet-with-gravitational-pu.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/701618/how-could-i-simulate-planetary-gravity-that-has-an.html

Comment: Cool idea! Can you share with us what you've found on how to create gravity for a single planet? That might help us help you!

Comment: I will definitley try to pull those resources together in a list of links to those topics if that's legal here.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done easily by adding a normal force relative to the planet on the surrounding objects.

According to physics of [Universal gravitational force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation) you can calculate the gravitational force. Then calculated the normal force at the moment and add the force.

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    // Do the Force calculation (refer universal gravitation for more info)
    // Use numbers to adjust force, distance will be changing over time!
    forceSun = G x (massPlanet x massSun)/d^2;

    // Find the Normal direction
    Vector3 normalDirectionSun = (planet.position - sun.position).normalized;

    // calculate the force on the object from the planet
    Vector3 normalForceSun = normalDirection * forceSun;

    // Calculate for the other systems on your solar system similarly
    // Apply all these forces on current planet's rigidbody

    // Apply the force on the rigid body of the surrounding object/s
    rigidbody.AddForce(normalForceSun);

   // .... add forces of other objects. 
}
```

With various `m1, m2` values you will be able to make the system more realistic. As an example make the object move/accelerate towards the planets with higher mass.

Comment: @BenjaminJameson did you try this?

Comment: I am extremely thankful for you're prompt replies i have to say being a total noob i didn't expect that.  I've been working 18 hours a day for the last several so i haven't had time, I will try to post all the thinks i've found already.

Again thank you guys so much and i'm sorry I havent been able to try this yet Dinal24 I'm hoping to be able to by tomorrow night at the latest.

Comment: Is it possible to make the Gravity script only apply to the planet itself, not involving other planetary bodies, for design reasons I'm not planning on having a rotational system, and I want the ability to create and destroy the planets in game, so I'd like to avoid making Gravity and it's effects dependent on other bodies around it.

Comment: @BenjaminJameson I think its not possible that way! and when you talk about design reasons, you can easily  attach this to the every object in the  system and keep them as prefabs. In fact it will require some experience in unity and use methods such as `FindWithTag("Planet")` and get gravity and apply them on other game objects. Also if this answer was useful you can be grateful to me with and upvote and by accepting the answer!

Comment: @BenjaminJameson If you use a Gravity component, it can keep a static list (`static HashSet<Gravity>`) of all the active Gravities, and each instance will add/remove itself with OnEnable/OnDisable. This is basically the same as what Dinal24 suggested, but it's safer and more flexible, not depending on objects having a certain tag.